# Approximation of $\sin x$ in $L^2$-space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $L^2((0,\pi/2))$ be the space of all square integrable functions on the given 
interval and $\langle f,g\rangle :=\int_0^{\pi/2} \langle f,g\rangle _H \,\mathrm{d}x$ the scalar product with $\langle f,g\rangle_H=f\overline g$.

I want to find the best linear approximation of $f=\sin x$ in $L^2((0,\pi/2))$.

This is demanded to be done by using the orthogonal projection $P_v u=\frac{\langle u,v\rangle}{\langle v,v\rangle}v$.

Now since the approximation should be linear I get $v=x$ and $u=\sin x$. ($u$ should be projected onto $v$)

I computed $\langle u,v\rangle = \int_0^{\pi/2} x\cdot sin x\,\mathrm{d}x=1$ 
 and 
$\langle v,v\rangle =\int_0^{\pi/2} x^2\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi^3}{24}$

which would yield $P_v u = \frac{24}{\pi^3}x$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.

So you are in fact trying to find the orthogonal projection of the function $f(x) = \sin x$ to the subspace $M = \operatorname{span} \{x\}$.

The orthonormal basis for $M$ is $\left\{\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right\} = \left\{\frac{24}{\pi^3}x\right\}$ so the projection onto $M$ is given by $$P_Mu = \left\langle u, \frac{x}{\|x\|}\right\rangle \frac{x}{\|x\|} = \frac{\langle u, x\rangle}{\|x\|^2}\cdot x = \frac{\langle u, x\rangle}{\frac{\pi^3}{24}}\cdot x$$

In particular, $$P_Mf = \frac{\langle \sin x, x\rangle}{\frac{\pi^3}{24}}\cdot x= \frac{\pi^3}{24} \cdot x$$